# Issues while extracting data from corrupted database

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008-r2, recovery

I have a problem with a corrupted database that i need to extract the data from it..

as a start our database server crashed and we extracted the .mdf and .ldf files from the file system but it appears that a specific database “XYZ” was running some operations when the crash happened as when I was trying to attach i got the following error:

> The log scan number (218:387:1) passed to log scan in database ‘XYZ’
>   is not valid

so I hack attached it by creating a database with the same name and replaced the .mdf file and delete the new .ldf after stopping SQL SERVER Service to reproduce your scenario, and started it again.

i followed Paul Randal instructions from this [Link](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/checkdb-from-every-angle-emergency-mode-repair-the-very-very-last-resort/) as follows:

```
ALTER DATABASE [XYZ] SET EMERGENCY;
GO

ALTER DATABASE [XYZ] SET SINGLE_USER;
GO

DBCC CHECKDB (N’XYZ’, REPAIR_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS) WITH ALL_ERRORMSGS, NO_INFOMSGS;
GO
```

but when i ran the DBCC CHECKDB Command i faced the following message

> File activation failure. The physical file name “E:\Program
>   Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\XYZ_log.ldf” may be
>   incorrect. The log cannot be rebuilt because there were open
>   transactions/users when the database was shutdown, no checkpoint
>   occurred to the database, or the database was read-only. This error
>   could occur if the transaction log file was manually deleted or lost
>   due to a hardware or environment failure. Msg 5123, Level 16, State 1,
>   Line 1 CREATE FILE encountered operating system error 3(failed to
>   retrieve text for this error. Reason: 15105) while attempting to open
>   or create the physical file ‘C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\XYZ_log.ldf’. Msg 5024, Level
>   16, State 2, Line 1 No entry found for the primary log file in
>   sysfiles1. Could not rebuild the log. Msg 5028, Level 16, State 2,
>   Line 1 The system could not activate enough of the database to rebuild
>   the log. File activation failure. The physical file name “E:\Program
>   Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\XYZ_log.ldf” may be
>   incorrect. The log cannot be rebuilt because there were open
>   transactions/users when the database was shutdown, no checkpoint
>   occurred to the database, or the database was read-only. This error
>   could occur if the transaction log file was manually deleted or lost
>   due to a hardware or environment failure. Msg 5123, Level 16, State 1,
>   Line 1 CREATE FILE encountered operating system error 3(failed to
>   retrieve text for this error. Reason: 15105) while attempting to open
>   or create the physical file ‘C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\XYZ_log.ldf’. Msg 5024, Level
>   16, State 2, Line 1 No entry found for the primary log file in
>   sysfiles1. Could not rebuild the log. Msg 5028, Level 16, State 2,
>   Line 1 The system could not activate enough of the database to rebuild
>   the log. Msg 7909, Level 20, State 1, Line 1 The emergency-mode repair
>   failed.You must restore from backup.

so as a final resort i tried to SELECT INTO each table by itself in a new database, and it worked for 80% percent of the tables but when it comes to a specific table *"The most important one"* when i tried the SELECT INTO statement i faced the following error:

> Could not continue scan with NOLOCK due to data movement.

is there any solution for that, i got a hint to read each page by itself but I'm not able to find how can this be done.

I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2 btw

Thanks in advance,

Comment: This sounds more suitable for the DBA site, but why are you using NOLOCK?

Comment: Actually i'm not using NOLOCK, the full statement was typing is SELECT * INTO [new database].dbo.[table name] FROM [old table name]

Comment: sorry i mistakenly posted without completed my comment, i just edited it

Comment: And you're not using transaction level read uncommitted?

Comment: No, actually the database is in emergency mode if that can help

Comment: Can you please clarify on this 1.)your database is not usable since you faced checkdb error due to log issue ,then how can you run select * into

Comment: sorry if my question was not well organized, i was trying to state the problem from the start, as i mentioned i hack-attached the database by replacing the mdf files with a dummy database of the same name while the sql server service is stopped, so the database is online, then i set the emergency mode on for it to be able to select into

Comment: does the dbcc say these messages at last ....2013-01-20 15:45:45.560 spid51       Starting up database 'EmergencyDemo'.
2013-01-20 15:45:45.610 spid51       Starting up database 'EmergencyDemo'.
2013-01-20 15:45:45.630 spid51       Warning: The log for database 'EmergencyDemo' has been rebuilt. Transactional consistency has been lost. The RESTORE chain was broken, and the server no longer has context on the previous log files, so you will need to know what they were. consistency. The database has been put in dbo-only mode. When you are ready to make the database available for use,

Comment: Paste your dbcc output or final peices of log

Comment: question is updated with the full DBCC output, sorry for that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118750/discussion-between-thegameiswar-and-mahmoud-y-elatma).

Answer (score 0):

> Could not continue scan with NOLOCK due to data movement.

This error can also occur  when you select from a corrupted table

I was able to repro your entire issue,but i didn't copied log file as you did which may be the cause for your DBCC Failure

To avoid DBCC failure,try this steps..
1.Dont create log file
2.Just create database with same name and copy mdf file in same path

Then run below queries..

```
alter database yourdb set emergency;
go

alter database yourdb set single_user;
go
```

now run dbcc checkDB,this will rectify errors and may also delete data from your important table

```
DBCC CHECKDB (N'yourdb', REPAIR_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS) WITH ALL_ERRORMSGS, NO_INFOMSGS;
GO
```

This will complete successfully..

Now run below statements..

```
alter database  yourdb set online
go

alter database yourdb set multi_user
go
```